# How can I redirect to another page HTML onClick using JSON data

Tags: javascript, json

I have DYNAMIC HTML and the data I am getting from my JSON file.
I want to redirect to photographers page:

[image: photographer page]

when i click on one of the photographers box:

[image: photographer box]

in the home page, normaly i would use `<a href='x'>` tag but i'am using Template Literals in JS so I don't know if it is possible to redirect using Template Literals ?
Any idea of how could i redirect ?

MY JSON FILE [HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tm213.jpg)

This is my code:
HOMEPAGE

```
/////////////////////////////////////////// FETCH //////////////////////////////////////////////

function grabTheDataFromJSON(){
  fetch("./../JSON.json")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(dataJson => { 
        displayPhotographers(dataJson); //function is invoked here 
        displayByDefault(dataJson)      //function is invoked here 
    }).catch(error => console.error)
};

grabTheDataFromJSON();

///////////////////////////// DISPLAY PHOTOGRAPHERS BY DEFAULT ///////////////////////////////////

function displayByDefault(dataJson){
  dataJson.photographers.forEach(photographe => { 
      const photographersDiv = document.getElementById('container');
      const div = document.createElement("div");
      const photographerTemplate = `
      <div class="photographerContainer">
        <div id="${photographe.name}">
        <div class="portraitBox">
          <img src="${photographe.portrait}" alt="photo">
        </div>
        <h1 class="name">${photographe.name}</h1>
        </div>
        <p class="city">${photographe.city}, ${photographe.country}</p>
        <p class="tagline">${photographe.tagline}</p>
        <p class="price">${photographe.price}€/jour</p>
        <p class="tags">${photographe.tags.map(tag => `<span class="tag">#${tag}</span>`).join(" ")}</p>  
      </div>
      `  
      photographersDiv.appendChild(div);
      div.innerHTML = photographerTemplate;
  }); 
};
```

PHOTOGRAPHERS PAGE

```
/////////////////////////////////////////// FETCH //////////////////////////////////////////////

fetch('./../JSON.json')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then(JsonData => {
          photographerProfil(JsonData)// function invoked here          
    }).catch(error => console.error)

/////////////////////////// PHOTOGRAPHER'S PROFIL TEMPLATE ////////://///////////////////////////

function photographerProfil(JsonData){
    const domDiv = document.getElementById('photographer-container'); 
    const profilTemplate = `
      <div class="profil-container">
        <h2>${JsonData.photographers[0].name}</h2>
        <p>${JsonData.photographers[0].city}, ${JsonData.photographers[0].country}</p>
        <p class="tagline">${JsonData.photographers[0].tagline}</p>
        <p>${JsonData.photographers[0].tags.map(tag => `<button class='tags'>#${tag}</button>`).join(" ")}</p>
        <button id="test">Contactez-moi</button>
        <div class="photoBox">
            <img src="${JsonData.photographers[0].portrait}" alt="photo">
        </div>
      </div>
    `
    domDiv.innerHTML = profilTemplate;
    photographerWork(JsonData)  // function invoked here
    showModal();                // function invoked here
}
```

Comment: \`<a href="${photographer.url}">\` should work fine.

Comment: Hello terrymorse, thank you for your response, is it possible for to show me an example from the code above on how can i do it, because when i try it doesent work ( maybe because I have separed JS files for homepage and photographerspage) ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as HTML or JS care, a string is a string. If you get the URL as a string and put it into the template like you did the other strings, it should work fine.

So, like @terrymorse said, something like `<a href="${photographer.url}">` should do it.

Comment: i dont have an URL i have only a JSON file which i am getting the data from, and my JS files are separeed homepage JS and photographers JS, what i am trying to do is: i wan to add this ```<a href="${photographer.example}"> ``` and use inside my accueil.js file and grab the template literale from photographers.js, is it possibile ? thank you for your time

Comment: I am trying to put another Template Literale inside my "a" TAG , You are right Alyx  i can retourn any data from the arrey but can i redirect to another template literale this is my question, i was not very clear sorry

Comment: @EgzonBerisha So where is the URL that you want to link to? That data has to be somewhere, presumably in the JSON you are reading in.

Comment: @terrymorse for the monment i am working with an JSON file stored directely in my project, the JSON file it imitates the Server =>> see the photo i updated my code abow

Comment: @EgzonBerisha Once again, how are you associating a photographer with their web page? You obviously need to do that in order to link to their page. What does a sample photographer's page URL look like?

Comment: @terrymorse ohh i understand how to do it now, i just used the "a" tage in my template literale and i gave him the addres to redirect to which was  "photographers.html" and it is working, now i should try to make some conditions to display each one work individualy using the TL, thank you man for your help